# sessionImplementor class not found when setting hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I recently started on Spring MVC and I am using hibernate to persist data to the database. I was following this tutorial: http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/06/29/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-quick-start-from-scratch/ and I am stumped in figuring out this one error below.. I made sure that hibernate-core is in the class path and all the other libraries are placed in the class path..

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/SessionImplementor
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1845)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:384)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:840)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
... 25 more
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>


<!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost 
    port 3306 with username root and blank password. Change below if it's not 
    the case -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzahut" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>com.getty.pizzashop</value>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>


<!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- **************************************************************** -->
<!-- SPRING ANNOTATION PROCESSING -->
<!-- **************************************************************** -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.getty.pizzashop" />
```

Can someone please offer some guidance? Thanks.

Comment: What build system are you using? It looks like you have mismatching versions of Hibernate set up (perhaps Hibernate 3 on your classpath, but you specified Hibernate 4 in your XML)?

Comment: I am using hibernate 4.2.6.Final and I am using Spring 3.2.4.Release

Comment: `SessionImplementor` is in `org.hibernate.engine.spi`, not `org.hibernate.engine` and has been for all of Hibernate 4. You're using a version of something that's compiled against Hibernate 3, or you have some declaration somewhere in configuration you haven't posted using it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently migrated an old project from Hibernate 3.2 to 4.2. Indeed `SessionImplementor` moved from `org.hibernate.engine` to 
`org.hibernate.engine.spi`. Several other classes/interfaces were also moved.

I recently added this and other items to the [migration guide published by RedHat](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40).